# Jquery image slider not working

Tags: jquery, html

I can't figure it out at all. The images should be moved along every 3 seconds and then when it gets to the end of the images it replays.

```
'use strict':

$(function() {

    var width = 720;
    var animationSpeed = 1000;
    var pause = 3000;
    var currentSlide = 1;

    var $slider = $('#slider');
    var $slideContainer = $slider.find('.slides');
    var $slides = $slideContainer.find('.slide');

    var interval;

    function startSlider(){
         interval = setInterval(function() {
            $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, animationSpeed, function(){
                currentSlide++;
                if (currentSlide === $slides.length) {
                    currentSlide = 1;
                    $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
                }
            });
        }, pause);
    }

    function stopSlider() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    $slider.on('mouseenter', stopSlider).on('mouseleave', startSlider);

});
```

Comment: I was trying to follow this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkzVFB3Ba_o

Comment: nothing. The images didn't move.

Comment: press f12 and tell what error message you have got

Comment: It's probably something else. Thanks.

Comment: Is it OK, if i suggest you simple other solution with same effects?

Comment: Sure. I know there are plug ins but I was trying to get it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but i run you script and all works fine.
One thing, is after 'use script' should use semicolon

```
'use strict';
```